# How to determine which number among $\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt2$ is greater?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, real-numbers

How do I guess which number is greater by using logic? Are there any tricks for guessing?

Comment: note that $-2 = \sqrt{4} > \sqrt{9} = -3$

Comment: @user1952009 $\sqrt 4$ is not equal to $-2$ by any means!

Comment: @user1952009: note that $\sqrt x$ is a nonnegative number by definition (assuming nonnegative $x$).

Comment: @MPW it was a joke...

Comment: @user1952009: ok. Maybe my response was too ;)

Comment: @MPW I was trying to be fun

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Observe that $\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: This reasoning is circular because it either assumes that $\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{2} > \frac{1}{2}$ or that $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} > \sqrt{1}$.

Comment: @Jared: Huh? The RHS is a positive number, so the minuend on the LHS must be greater than the subtrahend. This is an excellent proof.

Comment: @MPW You are correct, I see my mistake now.

Comment: I cannot undo my erroneous downvote unless an edit is made...if so, I will, but otherwise take this comment as adding two up-votes to this answer.

Comment: @Jared: No need for that. I am glad that you considered leaving a comment with your downvote.

Answer (score 5):

It's extremely easy. Note that the square root function is [strictly increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) across the non-negative real numbers. Since $3>2$ it follows that $\sqrt3>\sqrt2$.

In general:

- Any function that is strictly increasing, like $\ln x$, will always preserve the direction of an inequality when it is applied to both sides.
- Any function that is strictly decreasing, like $e^{-x}$, will always flip the inequality's direction.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is defined on the set $(0,\infty)$, and that on that range, the derivative
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
is always $>0$. Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing, so in fact $\sqrt{a}< \sqrt{b}\iff a<b$ for any two $a,b\in(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $0 <b $ and $x <y $ then $bx <by $.  That's an axiom.

So if $a < b $ then $a^2 = a*a <a*b <b*b = b^2$

We can conclude that $\sqrt {a} < \sqrt {b} $ because if it weren't then $a = \sqrt {a}^2 < \sqrt {b}^2=b $ wouldn't be true. (If $\sqrt {a} \ge \sqrt {b}  $ then $\sqrt {a}^2 \ge \sqrt {b}^2$.)

So $\sqrt {2} < \sqrt {3}$ simply because $2 <3$.